# SQL Server transaction with custom template

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, transactions

I would ask a basilar thing, I would use the native transaction stuffs to rollback a bunch of tables if some conditions are verified.

I really have to check how many updates results based of some stored procedure that gather data from tables populated by input reports, too less changes or too many changes means rollback because we will reject the reports. I would implements this feature with the native transaction of T-SQL, this is a pseudo of my idea:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE mytest 
AS
BEGIN
    BEGIN TRANSACTION
    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC foo
        EXEC bar
        EXEC baz
    END TRY

    IF true
       COMMIT TRANSACTION
    ELSE
       ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
```

Of course, this is not working because of incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IF', maybe because it's not the right way to use transaction.

Fixed this I will think how to count the changes of a table, if need to use a temporary table or if I can use some SQL features. I'm search for docs or example but I'm, not finding anything.

Any hints?

Comment: The problem isn't the `IF...ELSE`, it's the `TRY...CATCH`. It's called a `TRY...CATCH` for a reason; because you need both a `TRY` *and* a `CATCH`. You're missing a `CATCH`.

Comment: I solved moving the end try after the if else statement, but i'm not sure is what i mean, have to do some test. I don't need the catch statement becase every stored procedure have inside an own working transaction to prevent from error. In this main stored procedure I don't have to handle logical error but semantical errors because tables are working but not acceptable for my purpose.

Comment: *"I don't need the catch statement"* Then you don't need the `TRY`. But you **need** a `CATCH` in your above SQL *because* you have a `TRY`.

Comment: *"I don't need the catch statement becase every stored procedure have inside an own working transaction to prevent from error."* Are you saying you declare and handle explicit transactions inside the Proc? If so, as an FYI, you should be aware that [nested transactions are a myth](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2630-nested-transactions-are-real/) in SQL Server.

Comment: Heh yes, thank you for the link. I'm going to read it. My project has changed his purpose while I was working on it. At the beginning every sp gather data and rollback inside when spot errors, the others can be processed without matter. That's why I put the single try-catch that prevent logical errors, but now that I ended up the main process I start thinking there can be semantical errors for example the count of the changes. Too many or too less are not good and is a reason to reject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pseudo-code is missing a catch block. Below is an example that includes the error handling and other improvements.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE mytest
AS
SET XACT_ABORT ON; --best practice with explict transactions in procs
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN;
    EXEC foo;
    EXEC bar;
    EXEC baz;
    IF (<your-validation-succeeded-condition-here>)
        COMMIT;
    ELSE
        ROLLBACK;
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK;
    THROW;
END CATCH;
```

Comment: All you guys have right, I cannot use the try without the catch block. Any hint for the validation? Can I use some tsql history to count the table changes?

Comment: @rivaldid, you could add output parameters to the stored procedures that return the number of rows affected and compare to a range of a MIN/MAX value range in your validation.

Comment: Genuinely curious, having read Erland Sommarskog's error-handling page, what is the point of catching and rolling back, can we not just remove the `TRY` and rely on `XACT_ABORT` to roll everything back? Am I missing something?

Comment: So you say XACT_ABORT act as try-cath on the entire code till the GO terminator, as you say begin-end don't instructs sql to begin and end a batch and is not important to insert because the GO do it and is not just a formal separator as most people think. In this scenario as I can see the try-cath statement further circumscribes the batch that will be rolled back, reducing from the full code to the specified part and mine is not this scenario because my specified part is the whole batch. So in this specific example is not needed and not all example will be like this. Is it correct?

Comment: @DanGuzman thank you for your solution, I already has this count because I'm using a specified extra date table. Thank you, I saved your blog address too ;)

Comment: @Charlieface, I use `XACT_ABORT ON` not so much for error handling but to ensure an open transaction is rolled back following a client timeout where no T-SQL code executes afterwards. It is somewhat redundant with the structured error handling.

Comment: So do you reckon that it's just as safe to leave out the `TRY/CATCH` and just use `XACT_ABORT ON` and `BEGIN TRAN / COMMIT`? Can this ever leave an open transaction, or fall through an exception to the commit?

Comment: @Charlieface, the only gap that comes to mind with `XACT_ABORT ON` alone is `RAISERROR`, where execution will continue and the transaction remain open.

Comment: That and a compile error I think. But I think the latter extremely unlikely outside of dev environment, and `RAISERROR` I only ever use for `NOWAIT` with low severity, otherwise just `THROW;`

Answer (score 1):

The problem, as I mention in the comment, isn't the `IF...ELSE` it's that you have no `CATCH`. A `TRY...CATCH` requires both a `TRY` **and** a `CATCH`; unlike an `IF...ELSE` which can only have an `IF`.

You likely, therefore, want something like this:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.MyTest AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    BEGIN TRANSACTION MyTransaction;
    BEGIN TRY
        EXEC FOO;
        EXEC BAR;
        EXEC BAZ;
    IF {Your Boolean Expression}
        COMMIT TRANSACTION MyTransaction;
    ELSE
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION MyTransaction;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION MyTransaction;
        THROW;
    END CATCH;

END;
```

Comment: Heh, basically identical, @DanGuzman . :) We *both* missed out `SET NOCOUNT ON;` though but good point on `XACT_ABORT`.

Comment: As a rule I don't put `BEGIN/END` in sprocs and triggers because it confuses and makes people think that is the end of the proc. The end of the proc is at the end of the batch at `GO`

Comment: I disagree with that sentiment entirely, @Charlieface .

Comment: Go ahead tell me. Not disagreeing necessarily, I'd like to hear the other side

Comment: Putting it there clearly helps show where th PROC starts, and ends. There's nothing in the documentation to say that a procedure ends with an `END`, because it doesn't. In fact, the documentation states quite the opposite, that the statement must be the only one on the batch.

Comment: It's not like, say, where people put a `;` prior to a `WITH`/`MERGE`; the semicolon itls documented as a statement terminator, and not terminating your statements is deprecated. Putting one at the start of statements that require the prior to be properly terminated, instead of properly terminating, will one day be a syntax error.